# Не работает inertia в laravel 8 белая страница

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Установил Laravel 8, Jetstream.

**app.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { InertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue';
import { InertiaForm } from 'laravel-jetstream';
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue';
Vue.mixin({ methods: { route } });
Vue.use(InertiaApp);
Vue.use(InertiaForm);
Vue.use(PortalVue);
const app = document.getElementById('app');
new Vue({
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: name => import(`@/Pages/${name}`).then(module => module.default),
            },
        }),
}).$mount(app);
```

**Dashboard.vue:**

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Dashboard
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                    <welcome />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'
    import Welcome from '@/Jetstream/Welcome'

    export default {
        mounted: console.log(this),
        components: {
            AppLayout,
            Welcome,
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Консоль в браузере:**

```
undefined
app.js:4301 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile_photo_url' of undefined"

found in

---> <AppLayout> at resources/js/Layouts/AppLayout.vue
       <Dashboard> at resources/js/Pages/Dashboard.vue
         <Inertia>
           <Root>
warn @ app.js:4301
app.js:5564 TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile_photo_url' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (2.js:1240)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:7218)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:7734)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:8145)
    at new Watcher (app.js:8134)
    at mountComponent (app.js:7741)
    at VueComponent../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js.Vue.$mount (app.js:12711)
    at VueComponent../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js.Vue.$mount (app.js:15611)
    at init (app.js:6792)
    at createComponent (app.js:9640)
```

В app.blade @inertia присутствует

Лара свежеустановленная. Ничего не могу понять, вывел в компонент `mounted: console.log(this),` в консоле как видите `undefined` т.е. в компонент вообще ничего не передаётся. Никак не могу понять как это исправить.

в app.js в resolveComponent пробовал по разному:

`resolveComponent: (name) => require('./Pages/${name}').default,`

`resolveComponent: (name) => require('./Pages/${name}').default,`

`resolveComponent: name => import('@/Pages/${name}').then(module => module.default),`

ничего не помогает.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for not being able to translate to Russian,

Looking at your code i think it might be the same issue i had. The answer to this problem can be found here. Hope it helps.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-jetsream-vue-error-after-upgrade-with-inertia

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: и по-русски: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]